# Manually Translating from a Virtual Address to a Physical Address

Tags: memory, architecture, operating-system, virtual-memory

I'm having some trouble finding the corresponding physical address of some virtual addresses. I am trying to follow a similar process to what I have seen online but am running into some problems. Here is some information:

The architecture has 32-bit virtual addresses, 1Kbyte pages, and a 20 bit physical address. Each page table is a one-dimensional array so that the index is the virtual page number and the content is the corresponding physical page number. (not all values will be used)

Index -> Value

0

1

2 -> 2

3

4

5 -> 3

6

7 -> 9

8

9 -> 1

10

11

12 -> 0

Here is a virtual address (in binary) that I am trying to convert to a physical address (in decimal).

11101010

Where I run into problems is that my interpretation is that because virtual addresses are 32 bits, I am supposed to append a ton of leading zeros to the left but that doesn't seem to lead anywhere since we aren't given an index for 0. Maybe I just don't understand the process but I have spent hours trying to figure out what to do for this case and just can't seem to figure it out. If you can't type out a full solution I'd at least appreciate a hint as to what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page table entry = address / page size ;
Page offset = address mod page size ;

You need to know the structure of the page table (information not given) to find the physical page frame within the entry. Multiply that by the pages size.